# how to get column name after using MySQL function inside query

Tags: php, mysql, database, unix-timestamp

I am trying to get UNIX timestamp from MySQL timestamp using MySQL function inside query but in result its returning function name instead of column name. i am pretty new in Database

my Query

```sql
SELECT VillageName, Village_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) 
FROM village 
WHERE timestamp >= FROM_UNIXTIME(1538198785)
```

Result

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [VillageName] => something 
                   [Village_id] => 1 
                   [UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)] => 1557233601 
          ) 
)
```

Expected result

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [VillageName] => something 
                   [Village_id] => 1 
                   [timestamp] => 1557233601 
          ) 
)
```

Comment: Use aliasing: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp)  as timestamp`